# Split by Space and add values - Python

Tags: python-3.x, split

I have a list like this,

```
sample_lsit = ['ST,PAT A V0068 04/18/19 07/02/19 54 7 0.00 70.42',
               'ST,PAT A V0068 04/18/19 07/02/19 54 8 0.00 70.42',
               'LK,LON J V0067 07/02/19 7 26 0.00 486.00',
               'LK,LON J V0074 07/02/19 7 28 0.00 194.00',
               'LN,BET W V0195 05/16/19 07/02/19 77 2 2.33 36.49',
               'LN,BET W V0195 05/16/19 07/02/19 77 3 2.38 33.16']
```

In values 3 and 4, dates are missing and that is how it is. I want `None` values in the position where dates are missing. I am trying to split each value in the list by space like this,

```
for i in sample_lsit:
    print(i.split(' '))
```

I am getting an output like this,

```
['ST,PAT', 'A', 'V0068', '04/18/19', '07/02/19', '54', '7', '0.00', '70.42']
['ST,PAT', 'A', 'V0068', '04/18/19', '07/02/19', '54', '8', '0.00', '70.42']
['LK,LON', 'J', 'V0067', '07/02/19', '7', '26', '0.00', '486.00']
['LK,LON', 'J', 'V0074', '07/02/19', '7', '28', '0.00', '194.00']
['LN,BET', 'W', 'V0195', '05/16/19', '07/02/19', '77', '2', '2.33', '36.49']
['LN,BET', 'W', 'V0195', '05/16/19', '07/02/19', '77', '3', '2.38', '33.16']
```

However, I need my output like this,

```
['ST,PAT', 'A', 'V0068', '04/18/19', '07/02/19', '54', '7', '0.00', '70.42']
['ST,PAT', 'A', 'V0068', '04/18/19', '07/02/19', '54', '8', '0.00', '70.42']
['LK,LON', 'J', 'V0067', None, '07/02/19', '7', '26', '0.00', '486.00']
['LK,LON', 'J', 'V0074', None, '07/02/19', '7', '28', '0.00', '194.00']
['LN,BET', 'W', 'V0195', '05/16/19', '07/02/19', '77', '2', '2.33', '36.49']
['LN,BET', 'W', 'V0195', '05/16/19', '07/02/19', '77', '3', '2.38', '33.16']
```

How can I achieve this? I have been searching for this split with space and add

Comment: `null` isn't valid python. Did you mean `None`?

Comment: How do you know what column is missing? Is there any givens? Is it just a date that can be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't to hard, the nasty part is that you have three spaces for a missing entry not just two.

```
sample_list = ['ST,PAT A V0068 04/18/19 07/02/19 54 7 0.00 70.42',
               'ST,PAT A V0068   04/18/19 07/02/19 54 8 0.00 70.42',
               'LK,LON J V0067   07/02/19 7 26 0.00 486.00',
               'LK,LON J V0074 07/02/19 7 28 0.00 194.00',
               'LN,BET W V0195 05/16/19 07/02/19 77 2 2.33 36.49',
               'LN,BET W V0195 05/16/19 07/02/19 77 3 2.38 33.16']
result = [[x if x else None for x in line.replace('   ', '  ').split(' ')] for line in sample_list]
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
['ST,PAT', 'A', 'V0068', '04/18/19', '07/02/19', '54', '7', '0.00', '70.42']
['ST,PAT', 'A', 'V0068', None, '04/18/19', '07/02/19', '54', '8', '0.00', '70.42']
['LK,LON', 'J', 'V0067', None, '07/02/19', '7', '26', '0.00', '486.00']
['LK,LON', 'J', 'V0074', '07/02/19', '7', '28', '0.00', '194.00']
['LN,BET', 'W', 'V0195', '05/16/19', '07/02/19', '77', '2', '2.33', '36.49']
['LN,BET', 'W', 'V0195', '05/16/19', '07/02/19', '77', '3', '2.38', '33.16']
```

Since list comprehension can be confusing for beginners to python, that one line above is equivalent to (more or less) the following:

```
result = []
for line in sample_list:
    temp = []
    for x in line.replace('   ', '  ').split(' '): # replace three spaces with just two before splitting
        if x: # If x is not an empty string than we can add it
            temp.append(x)
        else: # else it is None
            temp.append(None)
```

Comment: this is great. I understand  now that we can add None on between when there is a space. I went back and checked, I don't have spaces in between as I did a `re.sub(' + ', ' ', x)` along the way. But I still want to add None to keep the number of attributes in the list same. My request is can I edit my post and will you still be able to help?

Comment: I have edited the post. It'll be in its original format. Let me know if this helps, or if you need more information. Thank you!

Comment: With a list like that you are forced to do format checking like the other answer. Alternatively it may help to intercept it before you do regex on it.

Comment: yeah, this I am going back all the way before regex to see if I can do anything in there. Thank you suggestions.

Comment: I think I got a workaround with pattern matching for now. i.e. when you `x.split(' ')[4] is None` then make index 3 null and concatenate index 3 + index 4 .. I know it is not efficient, but a quick fix, if situations change, it won't behave the way we need since it is solely based on index. After searching about this, seems like I will run into a design issue, trying to learn here! Thank you for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a unique approach since without any knowledge of the input, you can't determine what value is missing.

For these instances, it's probably good to have some tests to perform on each value to find that it meets the correct format. This can be done in a number of ways, but all rely on some kind of testing to validate the input.

Easiest is to create a method that will validate the input list and fill in values where needed. In your case, if you know the second date will always be provided then you can perform a check that two consecutive values are dates. If not, add a None in the 3rd index:

```py
def test(input_list):
  try:
    datetime.strptime(input_list[3], "%m/%d/%y")
    datetime.strptime(input_list[4], "%m/%d/%y")
  except:
    input_list.insert(3, None)
```

The other option is use a schema validation library like voluptuous or good perform the check and fill in default values to fulfill your requirements.

```py
import good

def test(input_list):
  schema = good.Scheme([
    good.All(str, good.Length(6), good.Match('[A-Z]{2},[A-Z]{3}')),
    good.All(str, good.Length(1), good.Match('[A-Z]')),
    good.All(str, good.Length(5), good.Match('[A-Z]\d{4}')),
    good.All(str, good.Length(8), good.Date('%d/%m/%y'), good.Default(None)),
    good.All(str, good.Length(8), good.Date('%d/%m/%y')), 
 ...
 ])
 schema(input_list)
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, per comment on the above answer, I have to go back and check what is happening before `regex` operation. I will update.